# OpenID connect authentication is supported in karate

Tags: karate

OpenID connect authentication is supported in karate?
As part of our new product we need to intialise user using openid connect authentication.
Is this is supported in karate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any scheme that works over HTTP/S is possible, you just need to write a little glue code for that.

All this is explained in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example

Make sure you look at the demos, which includes OAuth and JWT examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo